# how to make dynamic Appbar title?

Tags: flutter, dart

how to make such a dynamic `Appbar` on scrolling?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6gfQp.gif)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

inside Scaffold you should just have body not appbar and use CustomScrollView for the body. for your CustomScrollView you should use Slivers that needs a List of Widgets(SliverAppBar and SliverList).
SliverList is your Scrollable content and SliverAppBar is your desire Appbar.

```
Scaffold(
  body: CustomScrollView(
    slivers: <Widget>[
      SliverAppBar(
        expandedHeight: 300,
        pinned: true,
        flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
          title: Text('the title of appbar'),
          background: Image.network(
              an image url,
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      SliverList(
        delegate: SliverChildListDelegate([
          your scorrable content. make sure your content is scrollable.
        ]),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

Comment: But can I somehow put a fixed AppBar in SliverAppbar?